# 'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'key'

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I'm pretty new to python so it's prolly a stupid mistake i made.

I'm making an api which can be called using an external link. when calling the link my django server gives the following error: "'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'key'"

Below is the code in which the error occures (definition of request, sql request and the model i use).
the error happens when i try to call planning.key. I believe django doesn't know which type of object it is and doesn't know how to retrieve data from it.

Hopefully somebody can see what i'm doing wrong.

code in which it's going wrong

```
def get(request):
    if not len(request.GET):
        raise WeegNetError(101)

    data = request.GET.copy()

    usr = user.checkUser(data)

    planning = libs.getPlanning(data['planningkey'])

    if not planning:
        raise WeegNetError(310)

    fields = {
        'key': planning.key,
        'reference': planning.reference,
        'startdate': planning.plan_start.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
        'enddate': None if not p.plan_end else planning.plan_end.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
        'product': planning.product,
        'address_from': {
                                'relation': planning.rel_from,
                                'street': planning.street_from,
                                'housenr': planning.housenr_from,
                                'zipcode': planning.zipcode_from,
                                'city': planning.city_from
                        },
        'address_to': {
                                'relation': planning.rel_to,
                                'street': planning.street_from,
                                'housenr': planning.housenr_to,
                                'zipcode': planning.zipcode_to,
                                'city': planning.city_to
                        }}
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(fields))
```

sql request

```
def getPlanning(planningkey):
    sqlQuery = """SELECT k.key, 
        pl.id,
        pl.reference As ref, 
        pl.plan_start , 
        pl.plan_end, 
        pr.title as product,
        r1.name AS rel_from, 
        loc1.address AS street_from, 
        loc1.housenr AS housenrfrom, 
        loc1.zipcode AS zipcode_from, 
        loc1.city AS city_from, 
        r2.name as rel_to,  
        loc2.address AS street_to, 
        loc2.housenr AS housenr_to,
        loc2.zipcode AS zipcode_to, 
        loc2.city AS city_to 
        FROM `planning` pl
        LEFT JOIN `keys` k
        ON pl.id = k.planning_id
        LEFT JOIN `product` pr
        ON pl.product_id = pr.id
        LEFT JOIN `relations` r1
        ON pl.from_owner = r1.id
        LEFT JOIN `relations` r2
        ON pl.to_owner = r2.id
        LEFT JOIN `depot` dep1
        ON pl.to_depot = dep1.id
        LEFT JOIN `locatie` loc1
        ON dep1.locatie_id = loc1.id
        LEFT JOIN `depot` dep2
        ON pl.from_depot = dep2.id
        LEFT JOIN `locatie` loc2
        ON dep2.locatie_id = loc2.id
        WHERE pl.id = (SELECT planning_id
        FROM `keys`
        WHERE `key` = %(planningkey)s)
        AND pl.deleted = 0"""

    from models import Planning
    try:
        return Planning.objects.raw(sqlQuery, {'planningkey': planningkey})
    except:
        return None
```

model

```
class Planning(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    plan_start = models.DateField(null=False)
    plan_end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, default=None)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=False)
    rel_from = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    street_from = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    housenr_from = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    zipcode_fom = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    city_from = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    rel_to = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    street_to = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    housenr_to = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    zipcode_to = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    city_to = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'planning'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Planning.objects.raw()` returns [`RawQuerySet` instance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/sql/#django.db.models.Manager.raw), which is different from model instance.

You need to iterate or slice on the `RawQuerySet` to access actual model instance and its properties

```
qs = planning.objects.raw()
qs[0].key
for x in qs:
    x.key
```